# Can I use python or php with Framework7/cordova?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, html-framework-7

I want to develop an app with Framework 7, how ever, I want to do some thing like accessing local database, processing data which seems inappropriate to use javascript code.

The app will be used on ios and android, can I use python or php program with that?

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry you cannot use python or php on client side since they are scripting languages and you need a server to run those scripts, Since phonegap is html5 base so you can use only html and javascript frameworks

Answer (score 3):

You can do PHP processing with a PHP script on a server and call it with AJAX from your JS code, if that's what you mean. Framework7 has AJAX call functionality integrated. Looks like jQuery AJAX, just with $$ instead of $.

```
$$.ajax({
    url: urlOfPhpScript,
    type: 'POST', //or 'GET'
    data: {
        inputParam1: valueOfInputParam1,
        inputParam2: valueOfInputParam2
    }, //data that you want to submit to the server as JS object
    dataType: 'json', //or e.g. 'xml'
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        //error handling
    },
    success: function(response, status, xhr) {
        var outputParam1 = response.outputParam1;
        var outputParam2 = response.outputParam2;
        //...
    }
});
```

The PHP script should then look like this:

```
<?php
$inputParam1 = $_POST['inputParam1'];
$inputParam2 = $_POST['inputParam2'];

//do your PHP processing

$output['outputParam1'] = $outputParam1;
$output['outputParam2'] = $outputParam2;

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo(json_encode($output));
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just change the extension of the files from `*.html` to `*.php` for the entire project, and you'll have a fully working framework7 + PHP.

**Don't forget to change links inside your code as well to `*.php/*`

[SolvedImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0N21.png)